# Is there a bpy function to convert from blender units to Imperial?

Tags: conversion, units

Is there a bpy function to convert from blender units to Imperial? something like:

```
   >>> blender_to_imperial(2.0)
   ... 6.562'
```

This functionality is present when showing edge lengths, but I can't seem to find a function that can return the conversion.

I found one in the [caliper script](https://code.google.com/p/macouno/source/browse/trunk/Blender/addons/caliper.py) by macouno, but am wondering if this isn't something that exists already in bpy.

Comment: I don't think `imperial` merits a tag..

Comment: it wasn't an arbitrary tag choice.

Comment: ok, you could document it then. I can't imagine any real use of this tag, it will probably be synonymized into a larger one sooner or later, one that will account for all units.

Comment: I don't personally use Imperial units, perhaps [tag:dimensions] or [tag:dimensioning] would be better

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `units` to cover them all, `blender-units`, `metric` etc. `dimensions` sounds a bit too far off, perhaps a post on meta?

Comment: if it starts to crop up a lot definitely a meta post - good point and worth talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found several internal conversion code in the source, like one in `view3d_ruler.c` for [`bpy.ops.view3d.ruler()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.ruler), or in `drawobject.c` for measurement stats, none of them with direct Python interface. No reference to it, too, in the API manual.

CMIIW, but I think we'll have to write one. All distributed addons so far, like [Measure Panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Panel_Measure), also write their own conversion function, and it looks like the [aforementioned addon](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/space_view3d_panel_measure.py) have several function we can use directly:

```
import space_view3d_panel_measure as pm

uinfo = pm.getUnitsInfo()    
print(pm.convertDistance(2, uinfo)) # prints 2.0m, 2.0 BU, or 6.56168'
                                    # depending on selected unit system.
```

Comment: cool, yeah seems like a basic requirement for international 'precision' based modelling tools, and nice to have a solid implementation to call at will.

Comment: this method works fine @Adhi, thank you! And using it in the edge sum script: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/3839812

Answer (score 1):

The question is old and now Blender has built-in utilities to convert text input to internal units, for example you can set 2in like this:

```
bpy.utils.units.to_value("IMPERIAL", "LENGTH", "2in")
```

Read more: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.units.html